# vkCreateSwapchainKHR(): surface capabilities not retrieved for this physical device

Tags: c++, windows, glfw, vulkan

I'm trying to create a swapchain after surface creation. Currently my window is being created with GLFW like this:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
GLFWWindow = glfwCreateWindow(Extent.Width, Extent.Height, _Name.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
```

I create my `VkInstance` like this:

```
    VkApplicationInfo AppInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO };
    AppInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_1;    //Should check if version is available vi vkEnumerateInstanceVersion().
    AppInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    AppInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0);
    AppInfo.pApplicationName = _AppName;
    AppInfo.pEngineName = "Game Studio";

#ifdef GS_DEBUG
    const char* InstanceLayers[] = { "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation" };
#else
    const char* InstanceLayers[] = nullptr;
#endif // GS_DEBUG

    const char* Extensions[] = { VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME, VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME };

    VkInstanceCreateInfo InstanceCreateInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO };
    InstanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &AppInfo;
    InstanceCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 1;
    InstanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = InstanceLayers;
    InstanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 2;
    InstanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = Extensions;

    GS_VK_CHECK(vkCreateInstance(&InstanceCreateInfo, ALLOCATOR, &Instance), "Failed to create Instance!")
```

My `VkDevice` like this:

```
    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures deviceFeatures = {};   //COME BACK TO

    const char* DeviceExtensions[] = { VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME };

    PhysicalDevice = CreatePhysicalDevice(_Instance);

    QueueInfo GraphicsQueueInfo;
    QueueInfo ComputeQueueInfo;
    QueueInfo TransferQueueInfo;

    GraphicsQueueInfo.QueueFlag = VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT;
    GraphicsQueueInfo.QueuePriority = 1.0f;
    ComputeQueueInfo.QueueFlag = VK_QUEUE_COMPUTE_BIT;
    ComputeQueueInfo.QueuePriority = 1.0f;
    TransferQueueInfo.QueueFlag = VK_QUEUE_TRANSFER_BIT;
    TransferQueueInfo.QueuePriority = 1.0f;

    QueueInfo QueueInfos[] = { GraphicsQueueInfo, ComputeQueueInfo, TransferQueueInfo };

    FVector<VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo> QueueCreateInfos = CreateQueueInfos(QueueInfos, 3, PhysicalDevice);

    VkDeviceCreateInfo DeviceCreateInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO };
    DeviceCreateInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = QueueCreateInfos.length();
    DeviceCreateInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = QueueCreateInfos.data();
    DeviceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 1;
    DeviceCreateInfo.pEnabledFeatures = &deviceFeatures;
    DeviceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = DeviceExtensions;

    auto ff = vkCreateDevice(PhysicalDevice, &DeviceCreateInfo, ALLOCATOR, &Device);

    Vk_Queue* Queues[] = { &GraphicsQueue, &ComputeQueue, &TransferQueue };

    SetVk_Queues(Queues, QueueCreateInfos);

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties(PhysicalDevice, &MemoryProperties);
```

Then I'm giving the `HWND` and `hInstance` to the surface through:

```
VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR WCreateInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WIN32_SURFACE_CREATE_INFO_KHR };
WCreateInfo.hwnd = SCAST(WindowsWindow*, _Window)->GetWindowObject();
WCreateInfo.hinstance = SCAST(WindowsWindow*, _Window)->GetHInstance();

GS_VK_CHECK(vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR(m_Instance, &WCreateInfo, ALLOCATOR, &Surface), "Failed to create Windows Surface!")
```

After that as required by the validation layers I query for support and capabilities:

```
VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR Capabilities;
auto CapResult = vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(_PD, Surface, &Capabilities);

VkBool32 Supports = 0;
auto SupResult = vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(_PD, _Device.GetGraphicsQueue().GetQueueIndex(), Surface, &Supports);
```

`vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR()` returns `VK_SUCCESS` and that the surface is supported, but `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR()` returns `VK_ERROR_SURFACE_LOST_KHR`. I tried switching the order of these two functions and still the same happens.

Finally when I try to create a swapchain:

```cpp
VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR SwapchainCreateInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR };

SwapchainCreateInfo.surface = _Surface;
SwapchainCreateInfo.minImageCount = 3;
SwapchainCreateInfo.imageFormat = _SurfaceFormat;
SwapchainCreateInfo.imageColorSpace = _SurfaceColorSpace;
SwapchainCreateInfo.imageExtent = _SurfaceExtent;
SwapchainCreateInfo.imageArrayLayers = 1;
SwapchainCreateInfo.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
SwapchainCreateInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
SwapchainCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1; // Optional
SwapchainCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
SwapchainCreateInfo.preTransform = VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR;
SwapchainCreateInfo.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
SwapchainCreateInfo.presentMode = _PresentMode;
SwapchainCreateInfo.clipped = VK_TRUE;
SwapchainCreateInfo.oldSwapchain = _OldSwapchain;
```

It fails with this `VK_RESULT`: `VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`, and the validation layers throw this warning:

```
UNASSIGNED-CoreValidation-DrawState-SwapchainCreateBeforeQuery(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 0 - vkCreateSwapchainKHR(): surface capabilities not retrieved for this physical device
    Objects: 1
        [0] 0x1fddb809470, type: 2, name: NULL
```

Even though I believe I have checked for capabilities.

My Instance has this extensions enabled which are all that are required for GLFW to function:

```
const char* Extensions[] = { VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME, VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME };
```

My thought is that there is something wrong with Vulkan, since I can not see where this could go wrong. I was thinking of creating an issue but I wanted to check with you guys first.

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information to definitively answer.  You need to include the total code for creating the instance, device and swap chain, otherwise trying to figure out what's wrong is just guessing.

Comment: Hi @Jherico, I just added the info you requested, if anything else is needed just ask. Thanks for the tip. P.S.: Queue creation seems to be working alright now since I fixed thanks to your answer to my other question.

Comment: What value is `_Device.GetGraphicsQueue().GetQueueIndex()` returning exactly?  You're not using the debug reporting functionality.  if you add the `VK_EXT_DEBUG_REPORT_EXTENSION_NAME` to your instance extensions and use `vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT` to assign a message handler, does it produce any output before or during the call to `vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR`?  Also, you don't appear to be calling `glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions`.  On my system that in fact returns only the two extensions you're requesting, but it may return something different on yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't setting the HWND and HInstance variables properly but the surface creation didn't complain about it, neither did the validation layers. And for some reason one of the query capabilities function didn't fail while the other did.

Answer (score 1):

You show the window creation, and the surface creation, but you don't include the instance creation code.  When you created the instance, did you ensure that you requested the extensions returned by `glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions`? What were the exact set of extensions requested?

If you didn't request any extensions, in particular if you're missing `VK_KHR_surface` and `VK_KHR_win32_surface` then it would be expected that some or all surface operations may fail.

Also, how are you populating `_SurfaceFormat`?

Finally, this looks wrong:

```
SwapchainCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 1; // Optional
SwapchainCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
```

If `pQueueFamilyIndices` is null, the `queueFamilyIndexCount` should be zero.

Comment: Answers should primarily consist of answers, not more questions. If there's not enough information to answer it, then request more in the comments section.

Comment: Hey Jherico, I did populate the instance extensions array with the required extensions. ```const char* Extensions[] = { VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME, VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME };``` Those are all the extensions GLFW requires, I tested it. Then I also tested how ```_SurfaceFormat``` is populated, which is now being done correctly. Finally I fixed the QueueFamily things. Even after all of this the application fails in the same way.